# How to print a javascript variable in a jQuery .html() function?

Tags: jquery, html, variables

I need to print a var in a jQuery .html() function.. How do i do this?

```
.html('<table><tr><td><!-- VAR PRINT HERE? --></tr></td>')
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming your variable is in JavaScript:

```
.html('<table><tr><td>' + variable_name_here + '</tr></td>')
```

This simply concatenates (adds, glues together) the first string, then your variable, then the second string.